# How to load image from root of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the structure of my Rails project

```
Root
  -app
  -bin
  -config
  -db
  -lib
  -log
  -public
  -spec
  -test
  -tmp
  -uploads
      -images
  -vendor
```

I want to access images in the directory of "Root/uploads/images"

I tried lots by googling, nothing got helpful, I am stuck on this. Please try to give a solution. It will be very thankful.

Comment: is there a chance that you're able to move your uploads to /public folder?

Comment: i know it is possible from public directory. but i want to know is it possible from other than public directory for security purpose,  or is there any other way for secure data storing?

Comment: What are your security concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    dir_path = "#{Rails.root}/uploads/images"
    available_files = Dir.entries(dir_path).map{|e| e.gsub(/\..*/,'')}.reject{|c| c.empty?}
    file_path = if available_files.include?(params[:image])
                  "#{dir_path}/#{params[:image]}"
                else
                  "#{dir_path}/404.jpg"
                end

    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=#{12.hours.to_i}"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
    render :text => open(path, "rb").read
  end
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
get "images/:image" => "images#show"
```

If security is your concern, you can add permission checks to the controller.